# How can I tirgger vsts rest API for a release with auto approver?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

We are automating the release trigger procedure.
in one of our scenarios we need to trigger release though rest api's, and triggering release should be auto approve.

is there a way I can auto approve the release, do we have any rest api which performs approval.

considering the account which is triggering it got permission to approve the release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tirgger vsts rest API for a release with auto approver?

For this issue ,you can use [Approvals - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) rest api :

```
PATCH https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/approvals/{approvalId}?api-version=5.1
```

Sample request body:

```
{
  "status": "approved",
  "comments": "go!"
}
```

If you want to performs approval,you only need to set `status` to `approved`.

With [Approvals - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api,you can get `approvalId`. You can add parameters to the request url according to your needs, and filter out the exact approval to get approvalId .

Below is my test result with postman :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this

$deployUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{ornizationName}/{projectName}/_apis/release/approvals/{approvalid}?api-version=5.1"

```
        $body = @{
            status       = "approved"
            comments        = "go !"
        } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
        "body= $body"

        $verb= "Patch"
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method $verb -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $deployUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)} -Body $body
```